# How to run a script after a choice is made in a tcl tk combobox

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm using [`ttk::combobox`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_combobox.htm) and I want to run a script each time a choice is made. But in the documentation only a `-postcommand` option exists, which runs the script *before* the choice. How can I run the script after the choice (I want to be able to know when a choice is made).

Also, the combobox is `-state readonly` so no choices can be made through the entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind to the `<<ComboboxSelected>>` virtual event, which the combobox generates every time after an item is chosen.

```
bind .combo <<ComboboxSelected>> {puts "chosen [%W get]"}
```